# Angular - Javascript - Error: Can't find variable : google after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, variables, google-maps-api-3

I built a website with Angular 2+ and included the Google Maps Api in my index.html file:

```
<script
      async
      defer
      src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?[myKey]&libraries=places">
</script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
```

After I reload the page only on my Iphone, the map won't show and I get the error: 
"Can't find variable : google"

On PC and Android it is working fine.

What can i do to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the scripts run out of order, which is a major gotcha of asynchronous script loading. The first script with `defer` or `async` attribute loads in parallel while browser continues, and only executes after loaded, while the second (synchronous) script blocks the browser and runs immediately after loaded (which takes place either after or before execution of the first script, so the order is unpredictable).

To maintain the order, either add `defer` to the second script and remove `async` from the first (making both equally `defer`and hence in order), or remove `defer` and `async` from the first script to make it load normally.

Comment: Hi Son, this was the solution to my problem. Thank you!!